# Assign new Property to an Object's Property From Variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm trying something like this but it does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var is_dizisi = new Object;
is_dizisi = {
    res_143 : "3048397161693571444c6",
    res_142 : "3048397161693571444c6c53",
    res_141 : "3048397161693571",
    res_140 : "3048397161693571444c6c"
}

var onizlemeResimKontrol = function (is_id) {
    is_dizisi[is_id].hata = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. What error are you getting.

You can also  define object like below:

```
var is_dizisi ={
    res_143 : "3048397161693571444c6",
    res_142 : "3048397161693571444c6c53",
    res_141 : "3048397161693571",
    res_140 : "3048397161693571444c6c"
}
```

I didn't get what you are doing with second function. Any description ?

Comment: im trying to assign a new property like this: is_dizisi.res_143.hata = 1

Comment: @Lupus "res_143" seems to be a string property. How would you like the object "is_dizisi" to look like after you´ve added "hata" to "res_143"?

Comment: but, what is use of 'is_id' will it be res_143 ?